# Score label in top left Corner for all devices

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, label

I’m new to programming and I recently did a tutorial that I found online to make a endless frogger game. The tutorial person didn’t show me how to do the score label and I have tried endlessly to find a video tutorial that will show me how to position a score label in the top left corner. I have tried using this code:

```
label.horizontalAlignmentMode = .Left
label.position = CGPoint(x:0.0, y:self.size.height)
```

but I have had no luck, It does not show up in the top left corner. So i tried another way to get it positioned in the corner and I played around with the values and ended up with this

```
scoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(frame.size.width / -2.231, frame.size.height / 2.29)
```

which positions it perfectly in the corner of the screen on the simulator, but not for all the devices. I have a seperate swift file for my score label with is here:

import Foundation
import SpriteKit
import UIKit

```
class Score: SKLabelNode {

var number = 0

init (num: Int) {

    super.init()

    fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    fontName = "Helvetica"
    fontSize = 150.0

    number = num
    text = "\(num)"

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func addOneToScore() {

    number++
    text = "\(number)"
   }
}
```

I have a world node that has a player inside it and the camera position is focused on the player. I have provided my game Scene class for you to have a look at. All I want is to be able to position a score label in the top left or top right corner of the screen for all devices.

```
import SpriteKit


enum BodyType:UInt32 {

case player = 1
case roadObject = 2
case waterObject = 4
case water = 8
case road = 16


}

enum LevelType:UInt32 {

case road, water

}


class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

//recongises swipe and tap gestures
let TapUpRec = UITapGestureRecognizer()

let swipeRightRec = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()
let swipeLeftRec = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()
let swipeDownRec = UISwipeGestureRecognizer()

//defines the attributes for level units.
var levelUnitCounter:CGFloat = 1    // Not sure, i think it starts the frog further up.
var levelUnitWidth:CGFloat = 0      //will be screenwidth
var levelUnitHeight:CGFloat = 50    // changes the height of the level units
var initialUnits:Int = 10           // tells how many level units will be spawned as you climb.


//defines the world node for the scene & defines the player image in a constant.
var screenWidth:CGFloat = 0
var screenHeight:CGFloat = 0
let worldNode:SKNode = SKNode()
let thePlayer:Player = Player(imageNamed: "Frog")
var increment:CGFloat = 0

// variables with boolean values to check if the player is on certain types of levels or objects.
var onLilyPad:Bool = false
var onWater:Bool = false
var onRoad:Bool = false

//same variable that checks if the player is dead.
var isDead:Bool = false

//variable that links with the swift file called object and (maybe passes it through :(  )
var waterObject:Object?

//creates a constant that will be the starting point of the player
let startingPosition:CGPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0)

var direction:CGFloat = 1

// var nodeToMove:Object?
// var moveInProgress:Bool = false

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    /* Setup your scene here */

    // Defines the view as the target defines the direction and calls the function (in red)
    swipeRightRec.addTarget(self, action:"swipedRight")
    swipeRightRec.direction = .Right
    self.view!.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRightRec)

    swipeLeftRec.addTarget(self, action: "swipedLeft")
    swipeLeftRec.direction = .Left
    self.view!.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeftRec)

    TapUpRec.addTarget(self, action: "tapUp")
    self.view!.addGestureRecognizer(TapUpRec)

    swipeDownRec.addTarget(self, action: "swipedDown")
    swipeDownRec.direction = .Down
    self.view!.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDownRec)

    //makes the background colour black and defines the screenWidth variable as sk view boundry
    self.backgroundColor = SKColor.greenColor()
    screenWidth = self.view!.bounds.width
    screenHeight = self.view!.bounds.height

    //makes the world able to have objects that can collide (I Think)
    physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

    //physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx:0.3, dy:0.0)

    //creates the world node point to be in the middle of the screen
    self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
    addChild(worldNode)


    let scoreLabel = Score(num: 0)
    scoreLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = .Left
    scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x:0.0, y:self.size.height)
    addChild(scoreLabel)

    //scoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(frame.size.width / -2.231, frame.size.height / 2.29)

    // let highscoreLabel = Score(num: 0)

    //adds a child node to the world node (so the player is playing within the world node)
    worldNode.addChild(thePlayer)
    thePlayer.position = startingPosition
    thePlayer.zPosition = 500                // zPosition is the order the player will be displayed.

    addLevelUnits()         //runs the func that addds levelUnits.

}

func addScoreLabels(){

}

// this function along with the next three run the swipe and tap gesture actions.
func swipedRight(){

    let amountToMove:CGFloat = levelUnitHeight

    let move:SKAction = SKAction.moveByX(amountToMove, y: 0, duration: 0.1)

    thePlayer.runAction(move) // links the action with the players

}

func swipedLeft(){

    let amountToMove:CGFloat = levelUnitHeight

    let move:SKAction = SKAction.moveByX(-amountToMove, y: 0, duration: 0.1)

    thePlayer.runAction(move)

}

func swipedDown(){

    let amountToMove:CGFloat = levelUnitHeight

    let move:SKAction = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -amountToMove, duration: 0.1)

    thePlayer.runAction(move)

    // clearNodes()

}

func tapUp(){

    let amountToMove:CGFloat = levelUnitHeight

    let move:SKAction = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: amountToMove, duration: 0.1)

    thePlayer.runAction(move)

    clearNodes()

}

func resetLevel(){

    //searches the world node for child nodes that have the name "levelUnit"
    worldNode.enumerateChildNodesWithName("levelUnit") {
        node, stop in

        //removes all the child nodes from the parent.
        node.removeFromParent()


    }

    levelUnitCounter = 1
    addLevelUnits()

}

func addLevelUnits() {

    for (var i = 0; i < initialUnits; i++ ) {

        createLevelUnit()

    }

}

func createLevelUnit() {

    if (direction == 1) {

        direction = -1
    } else {

        direction = 1
    }

    print(direction )


    let levelUnit:LevelUnit = LevelUnit()
    worldNode.addChild(levelUnit)
    levelUnit.zPosition = -1
    levelUnit.levelUnitWidth = screenWidth
    levelUnit.levelUnitHeight = levelUnitHeight
    levelUnit.direction = direction
    levelUnit.setUpLevel()

    levelUnit.position = CGPointMake( 0 ,  levelUnitCounter * levelUnitHeight)      // counts the level unit and multiplies it so t goes above the last level unit.

    levelUnitCounter++                                                              //constantly makes the level units appear.

}

func clearNodes(){


    var nodeCount:Int = 0

    worldNode.enumerateChildNodesWithName("levelUnit") {
        node, stop in


        let nodeLocation:CGPoint = self.convertPoint(node.position, fromNode: self.worldNode)   //converts cordinates of level units with the world node.

        if ( nodeLocation.x < -(self.screenWidth / 2) - self.levelUnitWidth ) { // checks to see if the node is off the screen.

            node.removeFromParent()

            print("levelUnit was removed", terminator: "")

        } else {

            nodeCount++

        }

    }

    print( "levelUnits in the scene is \(nodeCount)")

}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */

    worldNode.enumerateChildNodesWithName("levelUnit"){
        node, stop in

        let levelUnit:LevelUnit = node as! LevelUnit  //cast as an actual LevelUnit class


        levelUnit.enumerateChildNodesWithName("obstacle"){
            node, stop in

            let obstacle:Object = node as! Object   //cast as an actual Object class
            obstacle.update()


            let obstacleLocation:CGPoint = self.convertPoint(obstacle.position, fromNode: levelUnit)

            let buffer:CGFloat = 150


            if (obstacleLocation.x < -(self.screenWidth / 2) - buffer) {                                    //changes the speed of object when it reaches middle of the screen.

                levelUnit.changeSpeed()

                obstacle.position = CGPointMake(obstacle.position.x + (self.screenWidth + (buffer * 2))  , obstacle.position.y)


            } else if (obstacleLocation.x > (self.screenWidth / 2) + buffer  ) {                            //changes the speed of the object again.

                levelUnit.changeSpeed()

                obstacle.position = CGPointMake(obstacle.position.x - (self.screenWidth + (buffer * 2))  , obstacle.position.y)
            }

        }

    }

    // creates new level units if always centering horizontally

    let nextTier:CGFloat = (levelUnitCounter * levelUnitHeight) - (CGFloat(initialUnits) * levelUnitHeight)

    if (thePlayer.position.y > nextTier) {

        createLevelUnit()
    }

    //deal with the players location....

    let playerLocation:CGPoint = self.convertPoint(thePlayer.position, fromNode: worldNode)

    var repositionPlayer:Bool = false

    if ( playerLocation.x < -(screenWidth / 2)) {

        repositionPlayer = true

    } else  if ( playerLocation.x > (screenWidth / 2)) {

        repositionPlayer = true

    } else if ( playerLocation.y < 0) {

        repositionPlayer = true

    } else if ( playerLocation.y > screenHeight) {

        repositionPlayer = true

    }

    if (repositionPlayer == true) {

        /* great code for reference later */

        killPlayer()

        thePlayer.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)

    }

}

// this function centers the world node on teh player.
override func didSimulatePhysics() {



    self.centerOnNode(thePlayer)


    if (onLilyPad == true) {

        thePlayer.position = CGPointMake(thePlayer.position.x + waterObject!.xAmount , thePlayer.position.y)

    }

}

//centers the camera on the node world.
func centerOnNode(node:SKNode) {

    let cameraPositionInScene:CGPoint = self.convertPoint(node.position, fromNode: worldNode)
    worldNode.position = CGPoint(x: worldNode.position.x , y:worldNode.position.y - cameraPositionInScene.y  )

}

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    //  Defines the contact between objects.

    /// lily pad
    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == BodyType.player.rawValue && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == BodyType.waterObject.rawValue ) {

        waterObject = contact.bodyB.node!.parent as? Object
        onLilyPad = true

        self.removeActionForKey("checkOnLilyPad")

        let waterObjectLocation:CGPoint = self.convertPointToView(waterObject!.position)
        thePlayer.position = self.convertPointFromView(waterObjectLocation)

    } else if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == BodyType.waterObject.rawValue  && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == BodyType.player.rawValue ) {

        waterObject = contact.bodyA.node!.parent as? Object
        onLilyPad = true
        self.removeActionForKey("checkOnLilyPad")

        let waterObjectLocation:CGPoint = self.convertPointToView(waterObject!.position)
        thePlayer.position = self.convertPointFromView(waterObjectLocation)

    }

    //// check on water

    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == BodyType.player.rawValue  && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == BodyType.water.rawValue ) {

        onRoad = false
        onWater = true

        waitAndThenCheckOnLilyPad()


    } else if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == BodyType.water.rawValue  && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == BodyType.player.rawValue ) {

        onRoad = false
        onWater = true

        waitAndThenCheckOnLilyPad()

    }

    //// cars

    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == BodyType.player.rawValue  && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == BodyType.roadObject.rawValue ) {

        killPlayer()


    } else if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == BodyType.roadObject.rawValue  && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == BodyType.player.rawValue ) {

        killPlayer()


    }

    //// check on road

    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == BodyType.player.rawValue  && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == BodyType.road.rawValue ) {

        onRoad = true
        onWater = false
        onLilyPad = false

    } else if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == BodyType.road.rawValue  && contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask == BodyType.player.rawValue ) {

        onRoad = true
        onWater = false
        onLilyPad = false

    }

}

func waitAndThenCheckOnLilyPad() {

    let wait:SKAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(0.1)
    let check:SKAction = SKAction.runBlock(checkIfOnLilyPad)
    let seq:SKAction = SKAction.sequence([wait, check])
    self.runAction(seq, withKey:"checkOnLilyPad")

}

func checkIfOnLilyPad() {


    if ( onRoad == false) {

        if ( onWater == true && onLilyPad == false) {


            killPlayer()

        } else if ( onWater == true && onLilyPad == true) {

            print("safely on water")
            // maybe play sound here
        }

    }

}

func didEndContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {


    let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

    switch (contactMask) {

    case BodyType.waterObject.rawValue | BodyType.player.rawValue:

        onLilyPad = false
        waterObject = nil
        onWater = true

        waitAndThenCheckOnLilyPad()

    default:
        return

    }
}


func killPlayer() {


    if ( isDead == false) {

        isDead = true

        let fadeOut:SKAction = SKAction.fadeAlphaTo(0, duration: 0.2)
        let move:SKAction = SKAction.moveTo(startingPosition, duration: 0.2)
        let block:SKAction = SKAction.runBlock(revivePlayer)
        let seq:SKAction = SKAction.sequence([fadeOut, move, block])

        thePlayer.runAction(seq)

    }

}

func revivePlayer() {

    isDead = false
    onRoad = false
    onWater = false
    onLilyPad = false


    let fadeOut:SKAction = SKAction.fadeAlphaTo(0, duration: 0.2)
    let block:SKAction = SKAction.runBlock(resetLevel)
    let fadeIn:SKAction = SKAction.fadeAlphaTo(1, duration: 0.2)
    let seq:SKAction = SKAction.sequence([fadeOut, block, fadeIn])
    worldNode.runAction(seq)

    let wait:SKAction = SKAction.waitForDuration(1)
    let fadeIn2:SKAction = SKAction.fadeAlphaTo(1, duration: 0.2)
    let seq2:SKAction = SKAction.sequence([wait , fadeIn2])
    thePlayer.runAction(seq2)

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If other solutions don't work, you could try something like this:

```
import UIKit
var screenSize = UIScreen.mainscreen().bounds
var screenWidth = screenSize.width
var screenHeight = screenSize.height
```

This will get the dimensions of the screen and store them in the screenHeight and screenWidth variables. 
Then when you call scoreLabel.position you could say

```
scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: screenWidth / 10, y: screenHeight / 15)
```

Or something like that but experiment with the math until it is in the correct position.

If this doesn't work you may also need to declare the size or scoreLabel. Let me know if it works.

Swift 4 and Xcode 9 code:

```
let screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds
let screenWidth = screenSize.width
let screenHeight = screenSize.height
self.menuButton.position = CGPoint(x: screenWidth / 10, y: screenHeight / 15)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track with:

```
    let scoreLabel = Score(num: 0)
    scoreLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = .Left
    scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x:0.0, y:self.size.height)
    addChild(scoreLabel)
```

But I think you also need to add

```
scoreLabel.verticalAlignmentMode = .Top
```

as the default is.Baseline which would cause it draw most off the screen.

Comment: That didn't work. Could it be something to do with the world node?

Comment: Perhaps you could print(self.bounds) to know how the scene is positioned and what size it is.  Did change any of the code regarding the presentation of the scene in the view controller?